# Cisco Catalyst 2960S boots to "MLG System"

Tags: cisco, ios, cisco-catalyst

We have a brand new Cisco Catalyst 2960S that while connected to the console during boot is booting to the following:

```
File "flash:/c2960s-universalk9-mz.122-53.SE2/c2960s-universalk9-mz.122-53.SE2.bin" uncompressed and installed, entry point: 0x3000
executing...

MLG system
Project version:60s-003
DATE:1,09,2012
Enter system please input command.

Mlg->
```

- What is this prompt?
- How do I bypass and proceed with a normal boot?

Comment: Are you sure it's brand new? It looks like it already has a configuration.

Comment: 100% sure, its one of three that I ordered from my rep at CDW. The other two are operational in a stack, I was adding this third one into the stack when it wouldn't join I noticed this. The prompt it non-functinoal as far as I can tell. I tried guessing common command s like `?` and `version` and it returns `!ERROR!` for all.

Comment: If it's new I would call TAC, otherwise call your CDW rep and return it for a new one.  Unless you want to sell it on ebay to someone who wants to pull the .bin and check it out.

Comment: I formatted the flash and am currently in the process or doing an xmodem copy of a new firmware to the unit. Will update when complete.

Comment: Dont the newer switches have a tftp-dwnld command in ROMMON?

Comment: @cpt_fink yes, you are correct, it does indeed have tftp download. I would have much preferred to use this option but did not think it would work without IP configured. Would this have worked with a console only connection? How would I have addressed the tftp server?

Comment: Even better than TFTP would be USB, which I did suggest in my original comment on NE (before you deleted and moved it here).  Works on 2960S switches quite well. However, to do TFTP from ROMMON, you configure the IP information in ROMMON.

Comment: Thank you @YLearn I initially attempted this but couldn't figure out how to make it happen. I formatted a USB stick FAT32, copied the IOS onto it, attached it to the switch, booted it to ROMMON, typed `dir` and wasn't getting a directory listing for the device. Was I approaching this incorrectly? If so can you point me in the right direction on how to do this from the ROMMON? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't have great documentation anywhere I have found, but you can find details from the Cisco Support forums such as this post [here](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11647766/catalyst-2960s-software-recovery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though the IOS image was indeed the problem. I deleted booted into ROMMON, formatted the flash, uploaded a new IOS image and the switch boots successfully.